# How can I deactivate loading spinner after href link opens?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that, when clicked, a loading spinner div is added:

HTML:

```
<a class="button-solid" href="./appointments/" rel="noopener">
       Request Appointment
       <div class="lds-ring">
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
               <div></div>
       </div>
</a>
```

I have Javascript that adds a class "active" to `lds-ring` when the button is clicked. And CSS to make the spinner.

Javascript:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button-solid');

[...buttons].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    toggleLoadingSpinner(e);

  })
});


function toggleLoadingSpinner(e) {
  const loader = e.target.querySelector('.lds-ring');
  const loaderDivChildren = e.target.querySelectorAll('.lds-ring div');

  if (loader) {
    loader.classList.toggle('active');
    [...loaderDivChildren].forEach(child => child.classList.toggle('active'));
  }
}
```

Adding the spinner works when the button is clicked. However, I run into the problem where on mobile, if I click the button then go back to the previous page, the spinner is still spinning. I'm assuming this is due to back/forward cache? Clicking the button leads to another page on my website.

My question is, whats the most logical way to turn the spinner off (i.e. remove the 'active' class on the button) after the button is clicked AND the target link is open? So that when I click the button then go back, the spinner won't still be spinning.

I'm looking into different things like page unload. Or, target page load / readyState. I spent a few hours messing around with `visibilitychange` event listeners until I realized it was for opening new tabs, not opening links/pages within the same tab. Not really sure how to approach this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may write an `onload` event handler for this page and remove `active` class from all your elements. Btw, why are you adding `active` class to the children of `.lds-ring`? You can select them with `.lds-ring div`.

Comment: You could also (although I wouldn't recommend it) hijack the clicking on the href - first, `e.preventDefault() `, then hide the loader, and then `window.location.href =this.getAttribute('href')` to actually go to the link the user clicked.